# Showing that the Diophantine equation $3x^2 + 6y^6 + 1 = 8xy^3$ has no solutions $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I want to show that the Diophantine equation $3x^2 + 6y^6 + 1 = 8xy^3$ has no solutions $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I tried factoring, but didn't manage (but I'm not good at factoring). Then I tried reducing $\mod{7}$, but this didn't gave decisive results.

Comment: I think your problem statement is missing something... what do you want to show about the Diophantine equation?

Comment: I fixed the question with what I thought would be the correct question.  Please immediately edit it if my guess was wrong.

Comment: You were right in the modification, thanks! Indeed, I wanted to show that there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting it as $6y^6-8xy^3+3x^2+1=0$, we have a quadratic equation in $y^3$, so that

$$y^3={4x\pm\sqrt{(4x)^2-6(3x^2+1)}\over6}={4x\pm\sqrt{-(2x^2+6)}\over6}$$

The square root is imaginary for all real $x$, so there are not only no rational solutions, there aren't any real ones either.

Alternatively, it's a quadratic in $x$, with solution

$$x={4y^3\pm\sqrt{(4y^3)^2-3(6y^6+1)}\over3}={4y^3\pm\sqrt{-(2y^6+3)}\over3}$$

for which the square root is imaginary for real $y$. (For some reason I noticed the equation as a quadratic in $y^3$ first!)

Answer (score 4):

$$  3 u^2 - 8uv + 6 v^2 = \frac{1}{3} (3u-4v)^2 + \frac{2}{3} v^2  $$ is positive definite for real $u,v$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 4 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: The answer looks nice, but I'm a bit puzzled. Can you explain your factorization technique?

Comment: @JensWagemaker see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 1):

Let the pair $(a, b)$ soluation for that equation
$$
\\6\sqrt{2}>8=>
\\8ab^3=3a^2+6b^6+1\ge2\sqrt{18a^2b^6}+1>6\sqrt{2}|ab^3|\ge8|ab^3|\ge8ab^3=>
\\8ab^3>8ab^3
$$
A contradiction.

Comment: What is $AM$ and $GM$?

Comment: Arifmetic and Geometric mean.

Comment: How did you come up with these estimates?

Comment: if $a, b\ge 0$ then $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}$